# May a blue card dependent stay out of Germany for more than six months?

Tags: germany, blue-card

My wife is a pregnant (now in 6th month) and she wants to stay in India for almost 10 months (for delivery, visa for baby too), I want to know is there any article number that allows the blue card dependent to stay abroad for more than six months?

I asked the *Ausländeramt* they said it is not allowed for more than six months but I read in many blogs that blue card dependents are allowed maximum of 12 months. I would like to know about an article number that existed that allows to stay abroad for more than six months.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, the limit is 12 months for Blue card holders and their dependents. The relevant reference is § 51 Abs. 10 Aufenthaltsgesetz, see https://www.buzer.de/gesetz/4752/a65988.htm

Answer (score 2):

The limit for Blue card holders and their dependents is indeed 12 months instead of 6. The relevant reference is § 51 Abs. 10 Aufenthaltsgesetz, see http://buzer.de/gesetz/4752/a65988.htm

Additionally, the *Ausländeramt* even has some discretion to grant a permission to stay abroad for longer period of times in other cases so it's disappointing they would suggest that you are not allowed to do so.

Comment: [§51 (1)(7) AufthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0927) does allow the foreigners authority to set a longer period.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Indeed but § 51 Abs. 4 qualifies that a little (in particular by suggesting it's mostly intended of *Niederlassungserlaubnis* holders) and § 51 Abs. 10 is stronger so I would simply rely on that.

Comment: For this case yes, but for others, this should be granted by the foreigners authority due to the given reason.

Comment: (4) states: **A longer period shall generally be granted...** to holders possession of a permanent settlement permit. (basicly for any reason) For others, it *can* be granted for important, humanitarian, reasons.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Maybe, I am not familiar enough with current practice to judge but it's not obvious when reading the text. It's not safe over-interpreting a translation, “wird in der Regel” sounds weaker to me. The only reason for an authorization by the *Ausländerbehörde* explicitly mentioned is the one in § 51 Abs. 4, the other exceptions are implicit (no authorization needed). I imagine such an authorization could also be granted in exceptional cases (that's what I meant by “*mostly* intended”) but that's a very weak thread to hang on.

Comment: In any case, it seems we are in violent agreement about all that. Since it's not relevant to the question at hand so I am not sure what you want me to do with it.

Comment: 'Regel' means 'Rule', so this should be understood with **as a general rule** it should be granted. What is relevant to the question is why the foreigners authority **didn't know** about these 2 rules and gave the wrong answer.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes, that's exactly what I mean and “as a general rule” is weaker than “shall”. Shall leaves no discretion. It's indeed disappointing they tried to mislead the OP when the rules are so clear. I will add something about that.